# .NET Json Serialization, JSON_MaxJsonLengthExceeded when passing 2 Megabytes of data

Tags: .net, asp.net, json

What sets the JSON buffer length **other** than web.config or creating an instance of the JavaScriptSerializer?

Is anyone aware if ASP.Net, the .Net Framework,  IIS, IE force or impose a buffer lenght forced at 2 Megabytes or data?

So far [maxJsonLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx) is the only property I control.

All works as expected bellow 2Megabytes, but above that, it's JSON_MaxJsonLengthExceeded exception.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045984/javascriptserializer-maxjsonlength-exceeded-whats-the-best-practice-for-handlin

Comment: yes, it is what I started from, and now I am beyond that point, looking for other settings that could limit this, for example, httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600" in the web.config

Comment: so far I tested with a sample app and been able to recieve as much JSON data as I wanted through a AJAX request, at this point I suspect the 3rd party vendor of the server control we use are setting the limitions. I will confirm with them then close the question soon.

Comment: for the record, it was the 3rd party WebScheduler (Intersoft) that was overriding the property