# server side method using jquery ajax return type size is limited

Tags: jquery

I am calling server side method using jQuery AJAX and it returns me an array.
When the array size is small it is working well but when array size increases it is not accepting array from server side.

I think there is limitation in return size in jQuery AJAX method, can anybody help me to overcome this problem or suggest any alternate option to call my server side method which is returning big size array?

My client side code is like,

```javascript
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pagename.aspx/methodname',
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        methodname(data);
    }
});
```

In above my success function is not getting executed when there is more data in array but when there is less data it is executing it well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right. There is a limit. Please refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045984/javascriptserializer-maxjsonlength-exceeded-whats-the-best-practice-for-handli

Comment: You are right. There is a limit. Please refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045984/javascriptserializer-maxjsonlength-exceeded-whats-the-best-practice-for-handli

Answer (score 2):

Set up size here:

```xml
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="x">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Comment: Thanks to all for reply, problem has been resolved by adding following things in web.config file,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for reply, problem has been resolved by doing following things,
add this into your web.config file
add this,

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

and then add this portion inside `<ConfigSections>`,

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
```