# MCV5 - The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5, jsonresult

im having a trouble with my JsonResult of a MVC 5 call. My retorn data are really big and im getting this error:

Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

And I cant find the property MaxJsonLength in my object JsonResult.

Thanks 4 the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600157/how-to-set-the-maxjsonlength-property) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for MaxJsonLength like below

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
```